# Create a playlist using pygame.mixer

Tags: python, pygame

I have been trying to make a simple playlist that plays 3 songs one after the other the code below shows an attempt of that. Rather than playing the first song music1.mp3 it plays the last song music3.mp3 and stops playing. I have tried looking at similar questions but strugling to find a soloution.

Please if anyone can help give me some advice or some guidance it will be much appreciated.

Mike

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.display.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode ( ( 420 , 240 ) )

playlist = list()
playlist.append ( "music1.mp3" )
playlist.append ( "music2.mp3" )
playlist.append ( "music3.mp3" )

pygame.mixer.music.load ( playlist.pop() )  # Get the first track from the playlist
pygame.mixer.music.queue ( playlist.pop() ) # Queue the 2nd song
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent ( pygame.USEREVENT )    # Setup the end track event
pygame.mixer.music.play()           # Play the music

running = True
while running:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:    # A track has ended
         if len ( playlist ) > 0:       # If there are more tracks in the queue...
            pygame.mixer.music.queue ( playlist.pop() ) # Queue the next one in the list
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pygame.mixer.music.queue('next_song.mp3'). I have heard that this ques the song and is played after the current one is finished. I am a newbie to python. Started yesterday :)

Check the following link, you might get an idea http://www.nerdparadise.com/tech/python/pygame/basics/part3/

Answer (score 0):

list.pop() returns the last item in the list.
If you changed:

```
playlist.append ( "music1.mp3" )
playlist.append ( "music2.mp3" )
playlist.append ( "music3.mp3" )
```

to

```
playlist.append ( "music3.mp3" )
playlist.append ( "music2.mp3" )
playlist.append ( "music1.mp3" )
```

then it would work correctly.