# Music Player will only play first song in playlist then stop

Tags: python, time, operating-system, mp3, mutagen

Trying to make a playlist maker using pygame but it will only play the very first song on the list and it does load the next song but no audio is played

```
from pygame import mixer # Load the required library
from os import listdir
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
import time
k = listdir('C:/LOCAL')
print(k)
mixer.init()
for x in k:
   y = "C:/LOCAL/" + x
   print y
   mixer.music.load(y)
   mixer.music.play()
   tracklength = MP3(y).info.length
   print tracklength
   time.sleep(tracklength)
```

Comment: What does `y` return on the second song (the one that fails)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this code:

```
import time
import pygame
from os import listdir

pygame.mixer.init()
tracks = listdir('C:/LOCAL')

# Create the playlist.
playlist = list()
for track in tracks:
    playlist.append(track)

# Define the song end event.
SONG_END = pygame.endevent.USEREVENT + 1

pygame.mixer.music.load(playlist.pop())   # Load the first track to play.
pygame.mixer.music.queue(playlist.pop())  # Add the second track in queue.
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(SONG_END) # Set the event.
pygame.mixer.music.play()                 # Play.

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == SONG_END: # A track has ended.
            if len(playlist) > 0:  # Queue the next track if there is one.
                pygame.mixer.music.queue(playlist.pop())
```

You can also watch the following links:

- [NerdParadise - Music and sound effects tutorial](http://www.nerdparadise.com/tech/python/pygame/basics/part3/)
- [Create a playlist using pygame.mixer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764355/create-a-playlist-using-pygame-mixer)

Hope this is helpful.